# How to call a function if current time is greater then and less then a specific time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to call a function between specific hours.. Between 6:00:00 AM and 8:00:00 PM myFunction() should be executed.. otherwise otherFunction() should be executed.

```
if (new Date().getHours() > "6" && new Date().getHours() < "20") {
              myFunction();
} else {
              otherFunction();
}
```

The above sometimes works.. but i feel its not accurate... I was also using the moment.js and:

```
if (moment().format("h:mm:ss A") > "6:00:00 AM" && moment().format("h:mm:ss A") < "8:00:00 PM") {
```

I think I resolved it with:

```
    var now = moment();
    var amStart = moment('9:00 AM', 'h:mm A');
    var amFinish = moment('10:00 PM', 'h:mm A');
    if (now.isAfter(amStart) && now.isBefore(amFinish)) {
      console.log('Success Function');

    } else {
      console.log('Failure Function')
    }
```

Comment: `but i feel its not accurate`....how/why? What seems to be the problem/question?

Comment: Don't compare with strings, compare with numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use isAfter() and isBefore() method of moment js. [doc](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/)

```
   var date = new Date();
    if (moment(date).isAfter("6:00:00 AM") && moment(date).isBefore("8:00:00 PM") ) {
      successfuntion();
    } else {
      failerfunction();
    }
```

Here is a fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/Refatrafi/yps8L631/4/

Comment: that didn't work. TypeError: moment(...).format(...).isAfter is not a function

Comment: you need to give the format of new date() here moment(date, 'new date() format'). say (date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')

Comment: @substancev have made a jsfiddle and modified the code more so that you can understand.

Comment: your fiddle doesn't execute i get the same result.. maybe date needs to be Date

Comment: TypeError: moment(...).format(...).isAfter is not a function

Comment: The fiddle was not updating. here is the new one. https://jsfiddle.net/Refatrafi/yps8L631/4/

Answer (score 1):

`getHours()` returns a number, not a string, so you should compare with numbers.

You need to use `>=`, not `>`, because when it's `6:10`, `getHours()` will return `6`, and `6 > 6` is not true.

```
var hour = new Date().getHours();
if (hour >= 6 && hour < 20) {
    myFunction();
} else {
    otherFunction();
}
```

Comment: It should be `20` instead of `8`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
var now = moment();
var amStart = moment('9:00 AM', 'h:mm A');
var amFinish = moment('10:00 PM', 'h:mm A');
if (now.isAfter(amStart) && now.isBefore(amFinish)) {
  console.log('Success Function');

} else {
  console.log('Failure Function')
}
```